# Manifest Version 2 and Trying to Images and Open Popup Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

Manifest:

```
{
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-1.4.1.min.js"]   
   },
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_title": "Roblox Hat Notifier",
      "default_popup": "newbackground.html"
   },
   "description": "This tells you if Roblox is online and it checks for the most recently updated hats.  It keeps a list of up to 3 items.",
   "icons": {
      "16": "16.png",
      "48": "48.png"
   },
   "name": "Roblox Hat Notifier",
   "permissions": [ "http://www.roblox.com/", "tabs", "notifications" ],
   "version": "2.0.86"
}
```

Background script:

`This is the jquery script plus underneath of it is the rest of the script to run all of the code.`

Popup html:

```
<body>
    <div id="Main">
        <div class="Column">
            <a id="link1" class="linkc" onClick="gotoHat1(1)">
                <img id="img1" class="specimg" src="http://t7ak.roblox.com/585fcc1ac09e8dd42c50fb4874210283" />
                <span id="t1" class="TextEffect">Woodland Hooded Disguise</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="Column">
            <a id="link2" class="linkc" onClick="gotoHat2(2)">
                <img id="img2" class="specimg" src="http://t7ak.roblox.com/585fcc1ac09e8dd42c50fb4874210283" />
                <span id="t2" class="TextEffect">BlARG</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="Column">
            <a id="link3" class="linkc" onClick="gotoHat3(3)" >
                <img id="img3" class="specimg" src="http://t7ak.roblox.com/585fcc1ac09e8dd42c50fb4874210283" />
                <span id="t3" class="TextEffect">BlARG</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="Box">
            <center><h2 class="tt">Most Recently Updated Hat</h2></center>
            <center><h4 id="t4" class="tt">BLARG<h4>
            <img id="bigimg" class="bigimg" src="http://t7ak.roblox.com/585fcc1ac09e8dd42c50fb4874210283" /></center>
            <center><button value="EPIC" type="button" class="specbut" onClick="gotoHat(4)">Go To Most Recently Updated Hat</button></center>
            <center><h3 style="color:white;">Roblox Hat and Gear Notifier</h3>
            <b style="color:white;">Status: Alpha (No Public Version Available)</b></center>
            <center><button value="troll" type="button" class="specbut" onClick="BlogLink()"><b style="font-weight:bolder;"><i>Donate</i></b></button></center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = localStorage['LatestHatTitle1'];
        document.getElementById("img1").src = localStorage['LatestHatPic1'];
        document.getElementById("link1").href = localStorage['LatestHatLink1'];

        document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML = localStorage['LatestHatTitle2'];
        document.getElementById("img2").src = localStorage['LatestHatPic2'];
        document.getElementById("link2").href = localStorage['LatestHatLink2'];

        document.getElementById("t3").innerHTML = localStorage['LatestHatTitle3'];
        document.getElementById("img3").src = localStorage['LatestHatPic3'];
        document.getElementById("link3").href = localStorage['LatestHatLink3'];

        document.getElementById("t4").innerHTML = localStorage['LatestHatTitle'];
        document.getElementById("bigimg").src = localStorage['LatestHatPic'];
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-28313791-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

    </script>
</body>
```

I'm fully aware that I can't use scripts in the newest manifest security update, but I come to you guys to see how we could possibly find a way around that.  You can see that I'm trying to update the images plus I have buttons that open other windows.  Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: I imagine what you're asking is how to run a script in the popup page? If so, you can't put the script's source on the page, you need it in a separate file, then set the script tag's src attribute to the file.